# What is the regex pattern of a string?

Tags: regex, string, vbscript

What is the regex pattern of the following:

```
APPLICATION_CONTEXT.getBean("giisParameterFacadeService")
```

Where the section of `giisParameterFacadeService` is dynamic.

I already tried:

```
"APPLICATION_CONTEXT[.]getBean[(]""\s*""[)]"
```

but it doesn't returns anything.

EDIT: Error occurred after changing it to: \w*

Line: 15. Char: 8. Error: Invalid procedure call or argument. Code. 800A0005

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile("sample.txt" , ForReading)  
Const ForReading = 1

Dim re
Set re = new regexp 
re.Pattern = "APPLICATION_CONTEXT[.]getBean[(]""\w*""[)]"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

Dim line
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.ReadLine
    For Each m In re.Execute(line)
       Wscript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
    Next
Loop
```

Comment: `\s` matches for whitespace. You might want `\w`, which matches `A-Za-z0-9_`

Comment: An error occurred after applying your suggestion. Line: 15. Char: 8. Error: Invalid procedure call or argument. Code. 800A0005

Comment: `Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set file = objFSO.OpenTextFile("sample.txt" , ForReading)  
Const ForReading = 1

Dim re
Set re = new regexp 
re.Pattern = "APPLICATION_CONTEXT[.]getBean[(]""\w*""[)]"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

Dim line
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.ReadLine
    For Each m In re.Execute(line)
       Wscript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
    Next
Loop`

Answer (score 1):

Other option (tested [here](http://www.regexr.com/)):

```
APPLICATION_CONTEXT\.getBean\(\"(.*)\"\)
```

Comment: This helped me! It doesn't really answered the question but it became the solution to what I am doing right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
APPLICATION_CONTEXT\.getBean[(]""\w*""[)]"
```